# Remove Outliers for NDVI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: outliers, google-earth-engine, landsat

I have the attached script in which I have calulated NDVI and NDMI yearly using Landsat8 for my ROI. But even after I masked out cloud pixels I still get outliers of NDVI and NDMI as NDVI and NDMI should stay conisistant in this region? Is there a way to remove outliers from my image or is there a way to improve my cloud mask? Also when I export of the CSV for the NDVI is there are reason that sometimes I get two diffrent values for NDVI and NDMI for the same date?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c8d297f17135e7648add714c82c7a075

I have changed the cloud mask a few time but get bad results.

Comment: Your link only works for people who have accounts on that system. Please paste your code into the question as text, in a code block.